# Грамотность речи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Странно слышать: “БОЛЕЕ(?) пяти человек”. Это сколько? Если большие числа- понятно, не уточняем. А более 5, 7, 10? Когда, в каких случаях правильнее говорить БОЛЕЕ?

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения современный нормы такое употребление скорее не является правильным.
Разные словари дают разную информацию. Ср.
То же, что больше **(в 1 и 2 знач.).** [Молчалин:] Ваш шпиц — прелестный шпиц, не более наперстка, Я гладил все его. Грибоедов, Горе от ума.

**Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.;**

БО'ЛЕЕ **(книжн.). 1. То же, что больше.** 2. В сочетании с прил. или нареч. служит для образования сравн. ст. (ему во второй части сравнения обычно соответствуют нареч. чем или нежели). Б. сильный сердечный припадок, чем прежде.

**Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940)**
**более
нареч.**

1. То же, что больше (в 1, 2 и 3 знач.) **(устар. и
   книжн.).**

**С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.**

Как видно из большинства словарей, уже тогда такое употребление имело пометы **уст. и книж.** Хотя и не все словари имеют пометы. Отсутствуют пометы и Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова (Грамота.ру). Это словарь института русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Более 7 не нормально, для тех кто не занимается конкретными подсчетами. Для меня, например, нормально звучит фраза: "Через створ наблюдения за ночь прошло более 6 особей семги." Значит наблюдатель видел 6 экземпляров, но наблюдал не всю ночь. (Понос прохватил пришлось часто бегать в кустики, или инфракрасные очки работали с перебоями.)

Интересно, а более 21, 147 или 1345 экз.  это для Вас нормально или нет? Если нет, то нормальность/ненормальность зависят не от **величины**, а от **точности** чисел.
И еще "больше/более 1" это вполне нормальное выражение по моему для всех.
По мнению историков наши предки считали 1, 2 и много, то есть более 2-х. Галки и современный человек считают (с одного взгляда, не пересчитывая пальцем) 1,2,3,4,5,6 и много.